# In GoogleGroups, how do you set the default Email Delivery option?

Tags: google-groups

When folks join my Google Group, they are defaulting to "no email".

I can't see how to change that default to "all email" or at least give them the choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to a Google Employee](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/apps/3OUlPmzKCi8/4f1gmhmWgcUJ) this is done on purpose on public groups to prevent people getting signed up and spammed.

The recommendation is to direct new users to the web interface (`https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/{GROUP_NAME}/join`) so that they can manage their settings. You might also direct your group members to this help page: https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1047839

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this. However, by going to the "Members" section, you can view and modify any or all members's delivery settings. So you can change their setting (even against their will, unfortunately) as soon as they join.

Answer (score -1):

if you go to the group settings > Permissions > basic permissions AND you activate that ANYONE can post messages you won't have any trouble with your new folks posting messages

Comment: this does not answer the OP’s question. it was about _receiving_ messages by default, not about _being able to send_ . quite an annoying default BTW.